# Overriding local controller with own new local controller

Tags: overrides, admin-controller, codepools

I've added some functionality to the Amasty_Xcoupon module, but after upgrading from v1.0.6 to 1.1.6, the codepool of the module changed from community to local. This somehow results in my controller not working anymore (404 page).

**Note**: I've updated the classnames and everything else works great. Also, I know there have been similar questions posted here, but the solutions mentioned there didn't work for me (or I messed up a bit more).

Here is the original rewritten controller (which worked when the module was in community codepool):

```
// src/app/code/local/My/Extension/controllers/Adminhtml/ReportController.php
class My_Extension_Adminhtml_ReportController extends Amasty_Xcoupon_Adminhtml_ReportController
{
    // code here
}
```

The older file was located in src/app/code/**community**/Amasty/Xcoupon/controllers/Adminhtml/ReportController.php, the newer is located in src/app/code/**local**/Amasty/Xcoupon/controllers/Adminhtml/**Amxcoupon**/ReportController.php.

This is the updated controller:

```
class My_Extension_Adminhtml_ReportController extends Amasty_Xcoupon_Adminhtml_Amxcoupon_ReportController
{
    // code here
}
```

The config.xml looks like this:

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <My_Extension before="Mage_Adminhtml">My_Extension_Adminhtml</My_Extension>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

This worked with the previous version, but now in the new version when execute the function I go to a nice looking 404 page, so my controller is no longer found.

I've tried using require_once to get the original controller, but no success. Also tried to change the config to this:

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <My_Extension before="Amasty_Xcoupon">My_Extension_Adminhtml</My_Extension>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

As well as adding the previously non-existing Amxcoupon directory in the controllers/Adminhtml directory and adding that to the config, but nothing works.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Many thanks to whoever finds the error(s) of my ways.

Comment: Have you tried adding dependency in your custom module, in your app/etc/modules/My_Extension.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial and error, I've found a way that worked.

First I did have to add the depencdency to my modules, like so:

```
<config>     
    <modules>
        <My_Extension>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Amasty_Xcoupon/>
            </depends>
        </My_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I also replaced the My/Extension/controller/Adminhtml/ReportController.php to My/Extension/Adminhtml/Amasty/Amxcoupon/ReportController.php to match the new file structure of the module.

Lastsly I needed to change the router rewrite, like so:

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <My_Extension before="Amasty_Xcoupon_Adminhtml">My_Extension_Adminhtml_Amasty</My_Extension>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```